# Get order custom meta data for PayTrace payment gateway in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, orders

I set up 3 custom checkout fields using WooCommerce's plugin 'Checkout Field Editor.' I have it set so that the fields are displayed on the emails and on the order screen, but I need for the info in those fields to also be sent to the Payment Processor, which is PayTrace. After speaking with the PayTrace Plugin developer, I have the code (link below) for adding additional information order info that is sent to PayTrace but I am not sure how to retrieve custom checkout field data properly/safely so that it can then be included.

Code for adding additional data in information sent to PayTrace.
https://gist.github.com/vanbo/dc3d9bc8660a7de33aafb44dde3033fa

Comment: Nobody can guess which are the fields to be sent… So your question is just unclear. You should at minima give some details related to that custom checkout fields and a live link to the related web site.

Comment: The Custom Checkout fields are named:
event_date
event_name
event_code

The Discretionary Data Fields set up on the PayTrace side are named:
Event code
Event date
Couples name

Answer (score 0):

In general Woocommerce Order meta data is mostly always prepended **with an underscore character**. For example the billing first name `meta_key` will be `_billing_first_name`.

For that reason you need first to check in **`wp_postmeta`** table for the last Woocommerce Order (`post_id` that is the order ID), to get the correct necessary **meta keys** that you will use in the following code.

Let say that your custom meta keys are:

- `_event_code` for **Event code**
- `_event_date` for **Event date**
- `_event_name` for **Event name**

Once done, you will get and set that data in the following code, something like:

```
add_filter( 'wc_paytrace_transaction_request', 'custom_data_paytrace_transaction_request', 10, 5 );
function prefix_filter_paytrace_transaction_request( $request_parameters, $order, $amount, $is_subscription, $is_paid_with_profile ) {
    $event_code = $order->get_meta( '_event_code', true );
    if( ! empty($event_code) )
        $request_parameters['event_code'] = $event_code;

    $event_date = $order->get_meta( '_event_date', true );
    if( ! empty($event_date) )
        $request_parameters['event_date'] = $event_date;

    $event_name = $order->get_meta( '_event_name', true );
    if( ! empty($event_name) )
        $request_parameters['event_name'] = $event_name;

    return $request_parameters;
}
```

You should need to check that the array keys for `$request_parameters` are the correct ones to be used.

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should works.